# redirect a whole group on condition with slim

Tags: authentication, redirect, routes, slim

I'm working with slim and I created groups for simplify my routes file.
But since a group should be unauthorized for non admin users, I would like to redirect all routes in this group instead of redirect all routes one by one like this:

index.php

```php
$app->group('/Admin', function () use ($app) { // crée un "groupe d'URL"

    $app->get('/users', function () use ($app){
        if(isset($_SESSION["type"]) && $_SESSION["type"] == "admin") {
            $ctrl = new UserController();
            $ctrl->listing($app);
        }else{
            $app->redirect($app->urlFor('indexAdmin'));
        }
    })


    $app->get('/users', function () use ($app){
        if(isset($_SESSION["type"]) && $_SESSION["type"] == "admin") {
            $ctrl = new UserController();
            $ctrl->listing($app);
        }else{
            $app->redirect($app->urlFor('indexAdmin'));
        }
    })
```

As you see the same code appears several times, is it possible to factorise it ?

Comment: [Middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/middleware/overview/) is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [route middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/middleware/).

Create your route middleware and add it to a variable:

```
$handleAuthorization = function () {
    if(!(isset($_SESSION["type"]) && $_SESSION["type"] == "admin")) {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('indexAdmin'));
    }
};
```

Create your routes using that route middleware variable:

```
$app->get('/', function (){
    echo "Home!!";
})->name('indexAdmin');

$app->group('/Admin', $handleAuthorization, function () use ($app) { // crée un "groupe d'URL"

    $app->get('/users', function () use ($app){
        $ctrl = new UserController();
        $ctrl->listing($app);
    });


    $app->get('/users2', function () use ($app){
        $ctrl = new UserController();
        $ctrl->listing($app);
    });
});
```